# AngularJs UI-mask not saving in database

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui

I use Angular UI-mask. but when I'm saving some values are not saving in db.
I need to generate a code like "xxxU99999". U value is a must. but U is not saving in db. why is that?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="containerEdit.CNo" name="CNo" ui-mask="AAAU99999" style="width:100px" ng-class="{ 'error': submitted && containerForm.CNo.$invalid }" required>
```

Comment: Ui mask just validates the input. I have no idea how you expect it to save to database.

Comment: What exactly do you want to save to the database? Like @cen said UI Mask is for validating input..

Comment: @Dsafds mmm I wanna create a code like "MSKU12345". the thing is "U" must be a default value.